# SimpleXML create feed - loop gives wrong output

Tags: php, magento, simplexml

Having problem with creating a datafeed with simpleXML. Currently using a loop to put products inside a data feed but the data of all the products is inserted inside the first product. Giving me the following output:

```
<products>
<product>
<product_id>36440</product_id>
<product_name>Snoerloze ramenwasser</product_name>
<brand/>
<description>
<h1>Droge schone ramen in een handomdraai... streeploos!</h1> <h3>Dankzij de nieuwe, inventieve draadloze ramenreiniger</h3> <ol> <li> Licht in gewicht, compact en extreem krachtig</li> <li>Bespaart u tijd</li> <li> Een snelle en effectieve manier om zowel binnen als buiten al uw ramen streeploos schoon en droog te maken.  </li> <li>Laat geen watersporen, strepen of druppels achter</li> </ol> <h3><br />Bent u die strepen op het raam ook zo beu? Dit is de nieuwe - tijdbesparende - leuke manier om uw ramen streeploos schoon te krijgen in een handomdraai.  Al het vuile water wordt opgezogen, zonder een druppel achter te laten. </h3> <p>Bestreepte, vuile ramen zijn verleden tijd, dankzij de snoerloze ramenwasser. Hij is gemakkelijk in gebruik, ideaal om condens druppels of kalkplekken tegen te gaan en om natte plekken snel en eenvoudig op te zuigen. Ideaal ook in de badkamer. Omdat de ramenwasser draadloos is kunt u hem zowel binnen als buiten gebruiken. Serres, badkamers, tafels, ramen en zelfs de caravan zijn in mum van tijd sprankelend schoon. Werkt op 4 AA alkaline batterijen, welke u van ons GRATIS meegeleverd krijgt!</p> <h3>Kinderlijk eenvoudig...</h3> <p>Spray het raamoppervlak in met uw favoriete glas reiniger, maak de oppervlakte schoon met een doek, en zuig met de ramenwasser het water weg. Zonder een druppel achter te laten, helemaal STREEPLOOS!... zo simpel is het!</p> <h3>Al het water wordt opgezogen in het interne waterreservoir. Voor een kristal helder STREEPLOOS resultaat zonder druppels.</h3>
</description>
<short_description>
Heeft u moeite om ruiten en spiegels streeploos te reinigen? Met deze ruitenreiniger wist en zuigt u in één handomdraai. Snoerloos, dus handzaam en licht van gewicht. Het water drupt niet op uw kozijnen of vensterbank, maar wordt door deze reiniger volledig opgezogen. Nawrijven is overbodig. Ideaal voor alle gladde oppervlakken.
</short_description>
<product_id>36287</product_id>
<product_name>Rekbare tuinslang 7,5m</product_name>
<brand/>
<description>
<h2>De meest ideale tuinslang ter wereld!</h2> <p>Sluit deze slang aan op de kraan en als het water erdoor stroomt verdubbelt de slang in lengte. Ideaal voor de tuin of het wassen van de buitenramen. Zodra u de watertoevoer sluit, krimpt de slang weer tot een klein handzaam pakketje. Inclusief aansluitstuk en instalbare spuitkop.</p>
</description>
<short_description>
</product>
<product/>
</products>
```

To create this feed i'm using the following php code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<products></products>');

$products = _prepareCollection();

$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

foreach($products as $productid)
{   
    $_product = $obj->load($productid);

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $model->load($productid);

    $_product->getFinalPrice();

    $product = $xml->addChild('product'); 
    $product->addChild('product_id',$_product->getSku());
    $product->addChild('product_name',$_product->getName());
    $product->addChild('brand',$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
    $product->addChild('description',html_entity_decode($_product->getDescription()));
    $product->addChild('short_description',html_entity_decode($_product->getShortDescription()));

}
```

Hope anyone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't actually have an answer, but after adding more childs into the feed the problem solved itself.

Working code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<products></products>');

$products = _prepareCollection();

$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 

foreach($products as $productid)
{   
    $_product = $obj->load($productid);

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product = $model->load($productid);

    $_product->getFinalPrice();

    $product = $xml->addChild('product'); 
    $product->addChild('product_id',$_product->getSku());
    $product->addChild('product_name',$_product->getName());
    $product->addChild('brand',$_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer'));
    $product->addChild('description',html_entity_decode($_product->getDescription()));
    $product->addChild('short_description',html_entity_decode($_product->getShortDescription()));
    $product->addChild('promotion_details');
    $product->addChild('deeplink',$_product->getProductUrl());
    $product->addChild('delivery_period');
    $product->addChild('delivery_cost','6.99');
    $product->addChild('stock_level');
    $product->addChild('stock_level_date');
    $product->addChild('embargo');
    $product->addChild('expiry');
    $product->addChild('currency');
    $product->addChild('display_price',$_product->getFinalPrice());
    $product->addChild('price',$_product->getFinalPrice());
    $product->addChild('image_thumbnail',$_product->getThumbnailUrl());
    $product->addChild('image_url',$_product->getImageUrl());
    $product->addChild('image_large_url',$_product->getImageUrl());
    $product->addChild('language');

    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    $categories = $product->addChild('categories');

    foreach($cats as $category_id)
    {
        $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id) ;

        $category = $categories->addChild('category');
        $category->addChild('category_id', $category_id);
        $category->addChild('category_name',$_cat->getName());
    }
}
```